# Overriding default identifier generation strategy has no effect on associations

Tags: php, symfony, oop, doctrine-orm, associations

Symfony 2.7.2. Doctrine ORM 2.4.7. MySQL 5.6.12. PHP 5.5.0.
I have an entity with custom ID generator strategy. It works flawlessly.
In some circumstances I have to override this strategy with a "handmade" Id. It works when the main entity is being flushed without associations. But it doesn't work with associations. This example error is thrown:

> An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO articles_tags (article_id, tag_id) VALUES (?, ?)' with params ["a004r0", 4]:
>
> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`sf-test1`.`articles_tags`, CONSTRAINT `FK_354053617294869C` FOREIGN KEY (`article_id`) REFERENCES `article` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE)

Here's how to reproduce:

1. [Install and create a Symfony2 application](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html#installing-the-symfony-installer).
2. Edit `app/config/parameters.yml` with your DB parameters.
3. Using the example `AppBundle` namespace, create `Article` and `Tag` entities in `src/AppBundle/Entity` directory.

   ```
   <?php
   // src/AppBundle/Entity/Article.php
   namespace AppBundle\Entity;

   use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

   /**
    * @ORM\Entity
    * @ORM\Table(name="article")
    */
   class Article
   {
       /**
        * @ORM\Column(type="string")
        * @ORM\Id
        * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="CUSTOM")
        * @ORM\CustomIdGenerator(class="AppBundle\Doctrine\ArticleNumberGenerator")
        */
       protected $id;

       /**
        * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
        */
       protected $title;

       /**
        * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Tag", inversedBy="articles" ,cascade={"all"})
        * @ORM\JoinTable(name="articles_tags")
        **/
       private $tags;

       public function setId($id)
       {
           $this->id = $id;
       }
   }
   ```

   ```
   <?php
   // src/AppBundle/Entity/Tag.php
   namespace AppBundle\Entity;

   use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
   use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

   /**
    * @ORM\Entity
    * @ORM\Table(name="tag")
    */
   class Tag
   {
       /**
        * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
        * @ORM\Id
        * @ORM\GeneratedValue
        */
       protected $id;

       /**
        * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
        */
       protected $name;

       /**
        * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Article", mappedBy="tags")
        **/
       private $articles;
   }
   ```
4. Generate getters and setters for the above entities:

   ```
   php app/console doctrine:generate:entities AppBundle
   ```
5. Create `ArticleNumberGenerator` class in `src/AppBundle/Doctrine`:

   ```
   <?php
   // src/AppBundle/Doctrine/ArticleNumberGenerator.php
   namespace AppBundle\Doctrine;
   use Doctrine\ORM\Id\AbstractIdGenerator;
   use Doctrine\ORM\Query\ResultSetMapping;

   class ArticleNumberGenerator extends AbstractIdGenerator
   {
       public function generate(\Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager $em, $entity)
       {
           $rsm = new ResultSetMapping();
           $rsm->addScalarResult('id', 'article', 'string');
           $query = $em->createNativeQuery('select max(`id`) as id from `article` where `id` like :id_pattern', $rsm);
           $query->setParameter('id_pattern', 'a___r_');
           $idMax = (int) substr($query->getSingleScalarResult(), 1, 3);
           $idMax++;
           return 'a' . str_pad($idMax, 3, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT) . 'r0';
       }
   }
   ```
6. Create database: `php app/console doctrine:database:create`.
7. Create tables: `php app/console doctrine:schema:create`.
8. Edit the example AppBundle `DefaultController` located in `src\AppBundle\Controller`. Replace the content with:

   ```
   <?php
   // src/AppBundle/Controller/DefaultController.php
   namespace AppBundle\Controller;

   use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
   use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
   use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
   use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

   use AppBundle\Entity\Article;
   use AppBundle\Entity\Tag;

   class DefaultController extends Controller
   {
       /**
        * @Route("/create-default")
        */
       public function createDefaultAction()
       {
           $tag = new Tag();
           $tag->setName('Tag ' . rand(1, 99));

           $article = new Article();
           $article->setTitle('Test article ' . rand(1, 999));
           $article->getTags()->add($tag);

           $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

           $em->getConnection()->beginTransaction();
           $em->persist($article);

           try {
               $em->flush();
               $em->getConnection()->commit();
           } catch (\RuntimeException $e) {
               $em->getConnection()->rollBack();
               throw $e;
           }

           return new Response('Created article id ' . $article->getId() . '.');
       }

       /**
        * @Route("/create-handmade/{handmade}")
        */
       public function createHandmadeAction($handmade)
       {
           $tag = new Tag();
           $tag->setName('Tag ' . rand(1, 99));

           $article = new Article();
           $article->setTitle('Test article ' . rand(1, 999));
           $article->getTags()->add($tag);

           $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

           $em->getConnection()->beginTransaction();
           $em->persist($article);

           $metadata = $em->getClassMetadata(get_class($article));
           $metadata->setIdGeneratorType(\Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadata::GENERATOR_TYPE_NONE);
           $article->setId($handmade);

           try {
               $em->flush();
               $em->getConnection()->commit();
           } catch (\RuntimeException $e) {
               $em->getConnection()->rollBack();
               throw $e;
           }

           return new Response('Created article id ' . $article->getId() . '.');
       }
   }
   ```
9. Run server: `php app/console server:run`.
10. Navigate to http://127.0.0.1:8000/create-default. Refresh 2 times to see this message:

    > Created article id a003r0.
11. Now, navigate to http://127.0.0.1:8000/create-handmade/test. The expected result is:

    > Created article id test1.

    but instead you'll get the error:

    > An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO articles_tags (article_id, tag_id) VALUES (?, ?)' with params ["a004r0", 4]:
    >
    > SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`sf-test1`.`articles_tags`, CONSTRAINT `FK_354053617294869C` FOREIGN KEY (`article_id`) REFERENCES `article` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE)

    obviously because article with `id` "a004r0" does not exist.

If I comment-out `$article->getTags()->add($tag);` in `createHandmadeAction`, it works - the result is:

> Created article id test.

and the database is updated accordingly:

```
id     | title
-------+----------------
a001r0 | Test article 204
a002r0 | Test article 12
a003r0 | Test article 549
test   | Test article 723
```

but not when a relationship is added. For a reason, Doctrine does not use the handmade `id` for associations, instead it uses the default Id generator strategy.

What's wrong here? How to convince the entity manager to use my handmade Ids for associations?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your problem is related with calling of `$em->persist($article);` before changing the `ClassMetadata`.

On persisting of new entity `UnitOfWork` generates `id` with `ArticleNumberGenerator` and saves it into `entityIdentifiers` field. Later `ManyToManyPersister` uses this value with help of `PersistentCollection` on filling of relation table row.

On calling `flush` `UoW` computes the change set of the entity and saves the actual id value - that's why you get correct data after commeting out of adding association. But it doesn't update data of `entityIdentifiers`.

To fix this you could just move `persist` behind changing of the ClassMetadata object. But the way still looks like hack. IMO the more optimal way is to write the custom generator that will use assigned id if the one is provided or to generate new.

**PS**. The another thing that should be taken into account - your way of the generation id is not safe, it will produce duplicated ids upon the high-load.

**UPD**
Missed that `UoW` doesn't use `idGeneratorType` (it is used by metadata factory to set proper `idGenerator` value) so you should set proper `idGenerator`

```
/**
 * @Route("/create-handmade/{handmade}")
 */
public function createHandmadeAction($handmade)
{
    $tag = new Tag();
    $tag->setName('Tag ' . rand(1, 99));

    $article = new Article();
    $article->setTitle('Test article ' . rand(1, 999));
    $article->getTags()->add($tag);

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $em->getConnection()->beginTransaction();

    $metadata = $em->getClassMetadata(get_class($article));
    $metadata->setIdGeneratorType(\Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadata::GENERATOR_TYPE_NONE);
    $metadata->setIdGenerator(new \Doctrine\ORM\Id\AssignedGenerator());
    $article->setId($handmade);

    $em->persist($article);

    try {
        $em->flush();
        $em->getConnection()->commit();
    } catch (\RuntimeException $e) {
        $em->getConnection()->rollBack();
        throw $e;
    }

    return new Response('Created article id ' . $article->getId() . '.');
}
```

This works like expected.

Comment: That's it. Tested in a production app with all types of associations - it works. Thanks!