# Doctrine ORM : is it possible to use an autogenerated id in other column on the same command?

Tags: php, database, postgresql, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have a table USER, with an `id` field configured like that :

```
* @ORM\Id
* @ORM\Column(type="integer")
* @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
```

I would want that the `firstName` column by default would be "user12" when id=12, or "user1547" when id=1547 etc.

I know I can obtain the same result from different way (ex: in my "Entity" with the `getFirstname` method, or, with a second command that update firstName value etc.) but it's not my point : I need that value in the database and it must be done on the same command that the one that "insert" my new user.

Do you think it's possible ?

I guess it's possible with `currval` on PostgreSql with a command like :

```
INSERT INTO user (id, firstname, lastname) values (nextval('user_id_seq'), ('user' || currval('tmp_play_id_seq')::text), 'Smith');
```

But what about Doctrine ?

Answer (score 1):

If you use autogenerated value, you don't know the new ID before you save it, means you can't  set your name to `firstIDVALUE`.

Doctrine is database agnostic, means it can't support specialised features of one database  over another, and need to just use common standardised features.

So there are few solutions I see now:

- Use [doctrine events](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/events.html#lifecycle-events), mainly I will look into postPersist, postFlush
- Set Id manually / [Explicitly set Id with Doctrine when using “AUTO” strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5301285/explicitly-set-id-with-doctrine-when-using-auto-strategy?rq=1) as described in that topic
- Maintain sequence separately and manage it by your code.